# PHP - rand() - random value from array of names

Tags: php, arrays, random

Task description is to use functions: count(), rand(), and strtoupper() to get random name printed out of my PHP array in all caps.
Code: http://ideone.com/nwjyoa

---

```
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
$friends=array("Mike", "Ondrej", "Honza", "Danca", "Misa", "Verca");
array_push($friends, "Michal", "Vendulka", "Daniela");
// Sort the list
sort($friends);
// Randomly select a winner!
$winner = array_rand($friends, 1);
echo "<p>$winner</p>";
// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
?>
```

I got so far to choosing a random value from the array, but it gives me its number(position), not a name :/
Could you please point me in the right direction to solving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `array_rand` returns an index, you should use that index into the `$friends` array to get its value.

```
$winner = array_rand($friends, 1);
$winner_name = strtoupper($friends[$winner]);
echo "<p>$winner_name</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If it returns the index, just fetch the value at that given index in the array:

```
$index = array_rand($friends, 1); // or $index = rand() % count($friends);
$winner = $friends[$index];
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to getting Randdom value-form Array.

```
$color_array =["red","green","blue","light_orange"];
$color_array[rand(0,3)]
```

now every time you will get different colors from Array.

> In your case.

```
 $friends[rand(0,8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array index. Just do $friends[$winner] instead.

```
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
$friends=array("Mike", "Ondrej", "Honza", "Danca", "Misa", "Verca");
array_push($friends, "Michal", "Vendulka", "Daniela");
// Sort the list
sort($friends);
// Randomly select a winner!
$winner = array_rand($friends, 1);
echo "<p>$friends[$winner]</p>";
// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use like below

```
echo $friends[$winner];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value from `array_rand` as a key for the `$friends` array.

```
$winner = strtoupper($friends[array_rand($friends, 1)]);
```

Comment: This one did not work for me when I replaced my definition of $winner.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$family_friends=array();

array_push($family_friends, "Marlon");
array_push($family_friends, "Johanna");
array_push($family_friends, "Leonary");
array_push($family_friends, "Sueann");
array_push($family_friends, "Olucho");
array_push($family_friends, "Allyah");
array_push($family_friends, "Reyna");
array_push($family_friends, "Cinil");
array_push($family_friends, "Carl");
array_push($family_friends, "Martain");
array_push($family_friends, "Christell");
array_push($family_friends, "Joy");

// Sort the list
$sorted = sort($family_friends);


$counted = count($family_friends);

print $counted;

// Randomly select a winner!

$win = array_rand($family_friends,1);

// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS

$winner = strtoupper($win);
print "<p>$family_friends[$winner] </p>"; ?>
```

Comment: There is already an (accepted) answer that looks like yours. What makes your answer better than the other(s)?